# Array of Objects that extends some Protocol into dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an object `Android` and `WindowsPhone` that extends the protocol `Phone` and I need to send all the `electronic` devices to a Web Service.

So...

```
let devices = [Android("111"), WindowsPhone("222")] // type: [Phone]
let params = ["electronic_devices": devices] // <----------- Error
let client.GET(..., parameters: params, ...) //AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

But I get `is not convertible to "StringLiteralConvertible"` in the second line.

How can I do it in a swift way?

Comment: Where, *exactly*, is the error?  You seem to indicate it's the second line, but that causes no trouble for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize each of those objects into an `NSDictionary` before you can send them in a network request.